# What's the difference between I've had and I've been having?

Tags: grammar

For example, what's the difference between:

*I've had a wonderful time here*
and
*I've been having a wonderful time*?

Does the present perfect simple indicate that the action is over?

Comment: When a member of the team says, "I have done my part." it may imply, my role is over, and it is now for others to do their part. Though the work is over, its impact continues till it  reaches a completion by all. When one says, "I have been doing it for a month", it implies that the action is not yet over, though it started a month ago.

Answer (score 0):

*I've had a wonderful time here* is what you say as you leave, indicating the time, sadly, must come to an end.

*I've been having a wonderful time* is what you might say as you explain that the time is no longer wonderful. As if to say the enjoyment has stopped suddenly. This is not actually wrong but uses an added layer of past perfect which adds nothing unless that is what you wanted.

A simple basic rule, my great bugaboo, is to avoid the word *having* accept when describing an upcoming meal. I regularly hear people tell me they are having blonde hair and blue eyes or they are having a blue Toyota.

It is hard to do wrong just using *have*.

For breakfast we certainly will be having grapefruit and bacon, Yum!